# Rotate `tcolorbox` with shadow

Tags: rotating, tcolorbox, shadows

How to rotate a `tcolorbox` with shadow? I tried `tikz={rotate=15}` but as you can see on the bottom of the image, this gives not the desired result.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

        \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=16.6cm,drop large lifted shadow, width=5cm,tikz={rotate=15}]%
            test
        \end{tcolorbox}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `transform shape`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

        \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=16.6cm,drop large lifted shadow, width=5cm,tikz={rotate=15,transform shape}]%
            test
        \end{tcolorbox}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]