# How to emulate this page style from the comic book Watchmen?

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-manipulation, page

Basically, I want to create a page so that it looks like a "photograph" of a piece of paper (with text) over another piece of paper (also with text).

Is this possible in LaTeX? If yes how? I have no MWE, because I have no idea how to begin about creating something like this.... Maybe with `tikz`?

Here are a few examples of this style, taken from the comic book Watchmen:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `tcolorbox` supports such lifted shadows, see section `10.6.2 Lifted Shadows` of the manual.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Does it support rotation or diagonally aligned boxes?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223150/121799).

Comment: That's great! I'll play around with the options to see if I can emulate the same page style.

Comment: Cool. If you encounter problems, you'll have an MWE to play with.

Comment: Without having looked at the manual yet, the one issue I possibly foresee is getting the box to overlap with part of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`marmot` suggested the use of `tcolorbox` for boxes and I will add its `tcbposter` library to control boxes positioning on page. The advantge of this library in front of other `poster` solutions is that you can use with any poster size

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {%showframe,
            height=3cm,spacing=2mm,rows=2},
boxes = {colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!50,colupper=yellow!50},
]
\posterbox{name=A,column=1,below=top}{First box}
\posterbox[rotate=-5]{name=B,column=1,between=A and bottom}{Second box}
\posterbox{name=C,column=2,above=bottom}{Third box}
\posterbox[rotate=-15]{name=D,column=2,between=top and C,span=2}{Fourth box}
\posterbox[colback=red, remember as=X]{name=E,column=3,between=top and bottom}{Fifth box}
\end{tcbposter}\\[2cm]
\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {%showframe,
            height=4cm,spacing=1mm,rows=2},
boxes = {colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!50,colupper=yellow!50},
]
\posterbox[remember as=A]{name=A,column=1,below=top, span=2}{First box}
\posterbox[rotate=5, colback=orange]{name=B,column=1,between=A and bottom}{Second box}
\posterbox{name=C,column=2,above=bottom}{Third box}
\posterbox[rotate=3]{name=D,column=2,between=top and C,span=2}{Fourth box}
\posterbox[colback=green, rotate=-5]{name=E,column=3,between=top and bottom}{Fifth box}
\end{tcbposter}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[line width=1mm, cyan] (A.north) to[out=60,in=30] (X.south);

\end{document}
```

[image]